# Android: Load image from URL into imageView in Widget

Tags: android, widget

this is the first time I'm trying to deal with widgets.
I'm trying to create a Widget which is suppose to load a image from url and show it in ImageView.

I'm loading Image using ImageLoader and it loads image perfectly (I checked it via Logs) but I think there is a problem with setting it to image VIew!!!

here is my **updateAppWidget** method from my **AppWidgetProvider**:

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    final RemoteViews views;
    views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

    String imageUri = "http://...";

    imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

            if (loadedImage == null)
                Log.d("1111", "loadedImage is NULL");
            else
                Log.d("1111", "loadedImage is OK");

            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ivLastNews, loadedImage);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }
    });

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

**what I tried:**

1) I tried load bitmap from resources into imageView and it was OK.

2) I tried other methods for loading image into Bitmap like Picasso.

Does anyone knows what I did wrong?

Comment: Do you have any "failed binder transaction" error on your log ?

Comment: @Neeks: not really. {just this on: E/libEGL﹕ call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)} but I can add my entire logs, If it helps!?

Comment: How is your ImageLoader related to the view you want to update? As when the event handler onLoadingComplete I guess you want to update the view, but I don't see a relationshipt between the created RemoteViews and the loader itself.

Comment: @Peter: I suppose this line [ views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ivLastNews, loadedImage); ] would give loaded-bitmap to my ImageView. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. The line updates the bitmap of your image for the view.

Comment: But which view is the view in:public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage)?

Comment: Pardon. You are not using this parameter.

Comment: @Peter: I try using the view from inside of "imageLoader.loadImage" but app crashed because of NullPointerException.